# DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges is very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My application uses Entity Framework 6.1.0 and `DbContext` API.

It's a some kind of CAD system, and it is intended to edit some engineering documents. To detect the fact of changes in the document, I'm using `DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges`.

When document has large amount of data (approximately 20-25 thousands of entities), `DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges` is running **very slow**. Since this code is used to enable/disable "Save" command, it executes rather frequently from UI thread. This, in turn, hits application performance.

I've re-written this fragment:

```
    private Lazy<DbContext> context;

    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get
        {
            if (!context.IsValueCreated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return context.Value.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
        }
    }
```

to this one:

```
    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get
        {
            if (!context.IsValueCreated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var objectStateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context.Value).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;

            return
                objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Any() ||
                objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted).Any() ||
                objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified).Any();
        }
    }
```

and (it's a miracle!) everything works extremely fast.

Looks like `DbChangeTracker.HasChanges` implementation isn't optimal.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code snippet the call chain to HasChanges involves a call to DetectChanges. When using snapshot change tracking DetectChanges goes through all tracked entities to determine if any have changed so that HasChanges will return the correct result.

The second code snippet does not call DetectChanges but instead just asks the state manager about the states it already knows about. So if an entity has been modified but this has not yet been detected, then the second code snippet may return the wrong result.

There are a few ways of handling this, one of which is to use change tracking proxies instead of snapshot change tracking. I wrote a blog series on DetectChanges which describes the various options and tradeoffs in detail: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/. I would recommend reading through so that you can make a good choice about what kind of change tracking is best for your application.

Answer (score 2):

@Dennis, Detect changes enumerates all attached items. This means that if we are adding 1000 items the first item we add enumerates no items, the second enumerates 1 item and so on. So if we do the math for this we get as below

```
 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 999 + 1000

or:

N(N+1)/2
```

where in your case N is approximately 25,000; so imagine the total outputted sum. This function is of the class O(N^2), i.e.,  big O notation is the complexity of square of N which explains why it takes so long to add a large number of items.

The code as below has segregated 25,000 entities in 3 categories, i.e., Added, Deleted & modified & their total sum is still 25,000 as opposite to the previous 1 LOC that was returning N(N+1)/2. Hence the efficiency comparison of work.

```
objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Any() ||
                objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted).Any() ||
                objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified).Any()
```

Comment: The code in the question does not involve calling Add. It involves a single call to DetectChanges, which can still be slow for a large number of entities, but is not O(N^2).